# Dynamically add images to Android WheelView

Tags: android, android-adapter

I have been working on this issue for days now. I am using the kankan Android wheel example/library, but am wanting to dynamically add images to the wheel when a button is pressed. The image added depends on the button's text. It seems like a fairly easy task, but perhaps I am missing something. I tried calling the adapter's notifyDataChangedEvent() after passing and adding the selected image to the adapter's list of cached images. Debugging has showed that the images were being added to the list of images, but they are not showing up on the wheel. If someone could please help me out with this problem I would appreciate it!

**Code:**

```
public void addItem(String text) {

    for(Item c: Item.values()){
        if(c.getName().equals(text)) {
            slotMachineAdapter.addImage(c.getImage());
            break;
        }
    }
    slotMachineAdapter.notifyDataChangedEvent();
}
```

**Adapter**

```
private class SlotMachineAdapter extends AbstractWheelAdapter {
    // Image size
    final int IMAGE_WIDTH = 700;
    final int IMAGE_HEIGHT = 150;

    // Slot machine symbols
    private final int items[] = new int[] {
            R.mipmap.ic_flipper
    };

    // Cached images
    private List<SoftReference<Bitmap>> images;

    // Layout inflater
    private Context context;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public SlotMachineAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        images = new ArrayList<SoftReference<Bitmap>>();
        for (int id : items) {
            images.add(new SoftReference<Bitmap>(loadImage(id)));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Loads image from resources
     */
    private Bitmap loadImage(int id) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), id);
        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, true);
        bitmap.recycle();
        return scaled;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemsCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    // Layout params for image view
    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);

    @Override
    public View getItem(int index, View cachedView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView img;
        if (cachedView != null) {
            img = (ImageView) cachedView;
        } else {
            img = new ImageView(context);
        }
        img.setLayoutParams(params);
        SoftReference<Bitmap> bitmapRef = images.get(index);
        Bitmap bitmap = bitmapRef.get();
        if (bitmap == null) {
            bitmap = loadImage(items[index]);
            images.set(index, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
        }
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        return img;
    }

    //Adds image to list of images
    public void addImage(int img){
        images.add(new SoftReference<Bitmap>(loadImage(img)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the count you return referenced to `items` variable, But `addImage` function did not change `items` size. Try to change your code like below and test it again:

```
@Override
    public int getItemsCount() {
        return images.size();
    }
```

Comment: I knew it would be something so easy! I feel so dumb. Thanks so much John Steve

Comment: When so tired, just take some rest and everything gonna be ok :D